# How to replace the content of <td> in ajax data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I tried to change the text `IN` to green dot in `data[i].online` and the text `OUT` to red dot in `data[i].offline`.

This is what I have right now.

[image]

This is the result that I want.

[image]

I have already tried `.text()`, `.html()`. But these were not work for it.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        var html = '';
        var i;
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        html += '<tr>' +
        '<td>'+data[i].name+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+data[i].description+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+data[i].comment+'</td>'+
       '</tr>';
        }
       $('#show').html(html);
      },
      error: function(){
            alert('Fail to load data');
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you html row generation code as follows:

```
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    $('<td></td>').appendTo($(row)).html(data[i].name);
    $('<td></td>').appendTo($(row)).html(getDot(data[i].online));
    $('<td></td>').appendTo($(row)).html(getDot(data[i].offline));
    $('<td></td>').appendTo($(row)).html(data[i].comment);
    $('#show').append($(row));
}
```

Function to generate the DOT:

```
 function getDot(data){
    var div = '';
    if(data) {
      div = $('<div class="dot"></div>');
      if(data === 'IN') {
          $(div).addClass('green-dot');
      } else if(data === 'OUT') {
          $(div).addClass('red-dot');
      }
    }
    return div;
}
```

**CSS**:

```
div.dot {
    width : 20px;
    height : 20px;
    border-radius : 50%;
}

div.green-dot{
    background-color : green;
}

div.red-dot{
    background-color : red;
}
```

Check the demo in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divekarvinit/4xejLfug/7/).

Comment: This is not working. The text "IN" is get from the database. I want to change IN to the green dot.

Comment: What do you mean? For Alice, what is the value for the OUT column then?

Comment: There is no value for the OUT. Because Alice is online. If Alice is offline. There will show the OUT in the OUT column.

Comment: The column don't show the green dot  or red dot. But show the [Object object] instead.

Comment: @Haha Please check the update code and attached fiddle link

Comment: It works perfect. Thank you. You are saving my day.

Comment: Hi, Vinit. I have another problem happens after add your code. I updated the problem on my question above. Could you please check this question for me?

Comment: You shouldn't edit the question. Ask a new one please. Keep the original question as it was so that others can refer to it if they have same problem. Also in the new question, please elaborate what do you mean by "tried `text()` and `html()`?" Also, please show us the code for the table and the button which refreshes the table.